# Newbie JS DataTables question: How to initiate it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

Sorry for asking very newbie question, but I am completely new to web development and trying to build a simple 1-page site which will reflect some "table" data using DataTables package. I tried enomorous amount of different ways to initiate it, but with not much success.

What I am doing wrong? My code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/DataTables/datatables.css">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="/DataTables/datatables.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">


        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#example').DataTable();
        });


    </script>
</head>
<body>
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Position</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
        <td>System Architect</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Garrett Winters</td>
        <td>Accountant</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Wich data tables plugin do you use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you mean this plugin: https://datatables.net/

You are using an old version of jQuery that is not compatible with this plugin. 1.11.3 is really old and it's highly recommended to update. Using the latest (SO) version of jQuery will fix your problem as you can see in the snippet below. Any 3.x version should do the job.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#example').DataTable();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">

<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Position</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
        <td>System Architect</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Garrett Winters</td>
        <td>Accountant</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: You do not explain exactly why jQuery 1.11.3 not should work with DataTables.  Why?

Comment: No luck :( So let me reveal for future readers: The assumption is wrong. Here working on jQuery 1.9.1 -> **http://jsfiddle.net/0f9Ljfjr/**